# Subtraction 2 coordinate

Tags: android, gps, sum, subtraction

when I subtract 2 coordinate(they are double) like 50.9430393 and 50.9430350 I get something like 2.998765E-8.... I've gotten this coordinates from GPS:

```
x2 = l.getLatitude();
dx = x2 - x1;
```

I have this prblem with sum, too ... why "-" and "+" don't work correctly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `E-8` is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), meaning 10 to the power -8.

The calculation works all right, it's just printing small or large floating point values that turns the formatting to scientific E notation.